# JavaScript - XMLHttpRequest to Raspberry PI on network ip fails on mobile, not on desktop

Tags: javascript, websocket, get, raspberry-pi, xmlhttprequest

I have a Raspberry PI on my network. I'm using WebSocket to connect to it and send commands. I connect to it by simply calling this line of code: `window.socket = new WebSocket(rpIP)` the `rpIP` could be `ws://10.58.3.146//ws`

But the PI's IP is dynamic, so i use the client (javascript) to scan for the PI on the network. I have set the PI up to respond at port 58 as the only device on the network.

My logic is that if i try to make a request to all possible 255 IPs on the network only one should respond. This works great on a desktop browser. I find the PI and I can send commands to it. But on a mobile device (i have tried both Android and iOS) it fails i get the following error: *net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED*

The scanner code:

```
let myIp = '10.58.3.33';
let ipToCheck = 0;
let targetPort = 58;
let rpIP;

checkIp();

function checkIp() {
    callError = false
    if(ipToCheck < 255 && !rpIP) {

        let ipArray = myIp.split('.');
        ipArray[3] = ipToCheck;

        addDebugMsg('Trying to connect to: ' + ipArray.join('.') + ':' + targetPort);

        let loading = setInterval(function() {
            addDebugMsg('.', false)
        }, 500);

        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('GET', location.protocol + '//' + ipArray.join('.') + ':' + targetPort, true);
        request.timeout = 1000;
        request.onload = function(e) {
            clearInterval(loading);
            console.log(e)

            if(request.status == 404) {
                addDebugMsg('nope! - Pi\'s not here');

                ipToCheck++;
                checkIp();
            } else {
                addDebugMsg('YAY! - We found the Pi');
                rpIP = protocol + '//' + ipArray.join('.') + '//ws';

                ipToCheck++;
                checkIp();
            }
        };

        request.ontimeout = function() {
            clearInterval(loading);
            addDebugMsg('nope! - Pi\'s not here');

            clearInterval(loading);
            ipToCheck++;
            checkIp();
        }

        request.send();
    } else {
        addDebugMsg('Scan done!');
        if(rpIP) {
            addDebugMsg('Found Rasberry PI at: ' + rpIP);
            window.socket = new WebSocket(rpIP);

            window.socket.onmessage = function(e) {
                handleSocketMessage(e.data);
            }

        } else {
            addDebugMsg('No Pi on network')
        }
    }
}
```

The `addDebugMsg` function is just a function i made to show on the page when is has found the PI.

Comment: Well of course it does. It encountered an error and you didn't handle an error.

Comment: To be clear, the code on mobile does find the correct IP but then fails at `window.socket = new WebSocket(rpIP);`, correct? (However I'm honestly surprised that this works at all, given that there's nothing to return 404 when you try to GET from a non-server)

Comment: @ChrisG to be clear. When the call (on mobile) does encounter an IP there does not time out the `request.send()` fails and gives the error.

Comment: Try adding `request.onerror = request.ontimeout;` before sending it. But still, I fail to see how this can work on the desktop. I'd expect the code to fail regardless where it runs.